# change tfs build service configuration from a Console Application

Tags: c#, tfs

I must use a public account to run a build service, the password of the account will change every some days.

I konw we can connect to a TFS from a Console Application with TFS APIs
(using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common; 
 using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;), 
and get the TFS information, I wonder if there is a API with which I can configure the property in the build configuration section. So that I can update the account's password once it's changed.

Also, do you have any other good ideas to auto update account and password in the build service configuration.

Comment: Did you mean you want to change TFS  service account's password by using TFS API? You can achieve this use command as mentioned in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552178(v=vs.120).aspx , then using code to call the command in a console application.

Comment: Hi, Patrick. Thanks for your feedback. Actrually it's not service account in Application Tier, which it says can be updated by: TFSConfig Accounts /change /accountType:ApplicationTier /account:AccountName /password:NewPassword.  It is under Team Foundation Server Administration Console -> Additional Tools and Components -> XAML Build Configuration -> Build Service Property -> Run the Service as, and the account here we use will change every some days (BTW, I use TFS2015). I  typed TFSConfig Accounts /? and looked into the accountType,  seems it dose not make sense for the account here

Comment: Yes you are right.  After more test, this command "TFSConig Accounts /UpdatePassword /account:TFSBuild /password:NewPassword

doesn't work. I got an error with `TF400892:The /accountType parameter is not allowed with the UpdatePassword operation` This is also make sense, since during the manually change password you need to stop and restart agent service(build agent), a simple command line should not achieved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this through command line, and there is no such TFS api to change the password of XAML  build service account.

You may have to change it manually on the machine by the follow steps as you mentioned:

1. In the **Services** pane, right-click **Visual Studio Team Foundation
   Build Service**.
2. Under **Service Status**, click **Stop**.
3. Click the **Log On** tab.
4. Specify the account you want to use for the service in the **This
   account** text box.
5. Type the new password in the **Password** text box, and then type the
   new password again in the **Confirm password** text box.
6. Under Service Status, click **Start**.